# Java Runtime Envoriment intallation problem

Tags: windows-7, installation, java

Hello i have a terrible problem with java.

I run Windows 7 64x and had a currpted Installation of Java. I couldn't uninstall cause error 1723 dll doenst exist. So i uninstalled java the regestry way. Now Java is gone from Installation explorer. I thougth all is fine.

But... If i try now to install java again i get a "is already installed" massage box. I have to diecide to install again or stop. When i pick install again another error comes up that this is only available for installed software...

What the h**l is going on? first he said its there then its not.... and i cant install the software :(

Were is java installer looking for existing installation and how can i get rid of it???

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Okay... I got it

in x64 there is another JavaSoft Folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node